# JQuery setInterval doesn't start at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to run a function every second but no matter what I have tried it never happens. I have even simplified the code to

`jQuery(function(){
     setInterval(function() {
                alert('interval');
            }, 300);
})`

but it just doesnt do anything. I'm not getting any errors and jquery is definitely installed properly

Comment: Your code works properly, my only guess would be that jQuery is *not* loaded property and you *are* getting an error - double check your console, e.g. in Chrome tools or Firebug to see what the cause is.

Comment: Warning - very annoying: http://jsfiddle.net/5f77s/embedded/result/

Comment: Does something else that setInterval work inside brackets? If you replace setInterval with alert('test')

Comment: Yes, the rest of the code works fine: it's just setInterval that never seems to work for some reason. Is there anything that could prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> jquery is definitely installed
>   properly

Are you trying to say that you have referenced the jquery file from the correct path, something like

```
<script src="padth to jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, jquery is installed becuase I am also using jqueryUI, as well as running other jquery commands to modify css e.t.c.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion guys, the code was correct and jQuery was installed. For some reason restarting my webserver corrected the problem, no idea what happened there.